# ASP.NET Web API Swagger (Swashbuckle) Duplicate OperationId

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a web api controller like below. 
[image: BarcodeImageController]
In swagger output I am having the below image
[image: Swagger Output]
And when I want to consume it in my another console app, it is showing the below error
[image: Swagger Rest Client Error]

Note I have followed the tutorial [Customize Swashbuckle-generated API definitions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-swashbuckle-customize/)  but still getting the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must need to add the Route Attribute on top of the Action methods. Like below:
[image: API Controller with Rotues]
So, the API changed into below Swagger UI endpoints
[image: Swagger UI]
And when I consumed this Swagger in my console app, the below OperationId I got
[image: List of OperationId]]
And I can now call like below (just an example)
[image: Console App Client Code]

Answer (score 4):

I found this while looking for the same question. For me it was a dumb mistake: the controller's methods had the same name. Apparently, Swashbuckle uses the method's name as the Operation Id.

Comment: For me it was adding the name in http method attribute combined with Route attribute. The route attribute template has to be removed and put into the Http method attribute.