# MapHttpRoute and Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to limit what shows up on swagger by limiting the routes available. Here are my current routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SiteCache",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Sites",
        action ="Cache"
    },
    constraints: new {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Delete),
        controller = "Sites"
    }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SitePost",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Sites",
        action ="Post"
    },
    constraints: new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post),
        controller = "Sites"
    }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new
    {
        controller = @"^(?:(?!Sites).)*$"
    }
);
```

That got rid of a couple routes I wanted to remove but I have two left that I'm trying to remove.

[image]

For the two with arrows in the image above, they are the same as the ones above them. I'm not sure why there is a redundancy here but I'd really like to get rid of the ones with the arrows.

What confuses me is I don't have the id as optional in Sites/{id}/Cache so why is that one even showing up.

The methods look like this:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ResponseMessage<Result> Cache([FromUri] string id)
{

[HttpPost]
public ResponseMessage<Result> Post(Site mainObj, [FromUri] string authKey)
{
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40432458/8215147) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624105/8215147) posts, I think that they may help you :)

Comment: @RuiFernandes adding the attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` to my methods will remove all of them from the documentation, so that doesn't help and I'm afraid swaggers restriction attribute will do the same. These two methods are generating two endpoints each in the documentation, I'm looking to remove those duplicates. What you've given me will remove them all.

Comment: Oh ok @jcaruso, I hadn't noticed it. My bad, sorry.

Comment: Hello again :) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843269/asp-net-web-api-swagger-swashbuckle-duplicate-operationid) now, it seems the same problem that you're facing and it was solved :)

Comment: @RuiFernandes I was able to use his solution, but it didn't work for me since I wanted the route to be the top delete instead I'm left with the bottom one.

Comment: Try with IDocument filter, with that you can Add/Remove anything from the swagger document that ultimately controls what is shown in the UI

Comment: @HelderSepu isn't the XML build at build time and placed into the bin directory?

Comment: XML build !?!?  are we talking about the same thing here? ... the swagger document also known as swagger.json looks like this: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1  ... that is generated at runtime

Comment: @HelderSepu I thought it was generated at build and placed into the `bin\SwaggerApi.XML`as output.

Comment: No that Xml is something else, that is from your project not from swagger or swashbuckle

Comment: Take a look at your SwaggerConfig for DocumentFilter https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L195